# Cisco Switch without VLAN support?

Tags: cisco, vlan, cisco-ios

I've been reading about [VLAN](https://www.dummies.com/programming/networking/creating-a-vlan-for-cisco-networking/) and wondering is there any Cisco Switches that do not support VLAN?

So far, all switches that I found do support VLAN. This is one of the example in my lab.

```
Cisco-Switch-#show vlan ?
  brief         VTP all VLAN status in brief
  group         VLAN group(s) information
  id            VTP VLAN status by VLAN id
  ifindex       SNMP ifIndex
  internal      VLAN internal usage
  mtu           VLAN MTU information
  name          VTP VLAN status by VLAN name
  private-vlan  Private VLAN information
  summary       VLAN summary information
  |             Output modifiers
  <cr>

Cisco-Switch-#
```

If there is, what are their model name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unmanaged switches generally don't support VLANs - Cisco sells those, too, like the [110 Series](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/switches/110-series-unmanaged-switches/index.html) switches (or the previous 100 Series, also they've got very small, unmanaged switches).

Answer (score 1):

Any switch which is not supported to 802.1Q are not support to VLAN tagging also. In cisco, Small business series un-managed switches are not support for vlan tagging.

Comment: `In cisco, Small business series un-managed switches are not support for vlan tagging.` That is utterly wrong. The larger part of Cisco's Small Business Series (SG200, SG 300 and SG350) series do support 802.1q tagging, VLANs, (Rapid) Per VLAN Spanning-Tree, even some 802.1x, IGMP snooping. Can't tell for the 100 series, though, but most do.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi Read Carefully In cisco, Small business series **un-managed switches** are not support for vlan tagging. SG200,SG300 are not un-managed Switch. Those are manageable switches

Answer (score -1):

Mostly all manageable Switches  of cisco supports Vlans . There are unmanaged switches where  Vlans are not supported.

Basically all manageable switch acts as unmanaged switch if we don't Configure anything . By default Vlan 1 is used if manage switch left un configured.

Comment: Unmanaged switches don't run STP, but all Cisco managed switches do,